# Unity transparent sprite render order

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, transparent, particles

I've been trying to fix this issue for a while. It's about the render order of transparent particle sprites, regardless of the shader used, some of the sprites from the background nebula are rendered above the foreground ones. The image should clarify the situation. The sprites are Quads with materials on them which happen to use the Legacy Shaders/Particles/Alpha Blended shader.

[image: render queue problem]

I've even tried setting the renderQueue of the foreground quads' materials to a value higher than that of the background quads, but even that didn't help
It seems whatever I do, the render order of the transparent sprites is messed up. The shader currenty used is Particles/Additive Blend, but using similar shaders didn't really help.

Comment: Both types of sprite are using the same shader right?

Comment: Yes, currently they are. I've tried to come up with an alpha blended shader which accounts for Z order, but haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Particle system geometry is batched, so the render order is determined by the particle system itself.  In the settings for the particle system, go to the last category "Rendering".  In there you should find a field called "Sort Mode" that determines which particles are put in front of others.  It sounds like you want the "By Distance" option.

Comment: I should probably rephrase the question to make it more accurate. These are not Unity particle systems, these are manually instantiated Quads with materials on them, which happen to use Particle shaders (Legacy Shaders/Particles/Alpha Blended)